# Exception creating client using AWS SDK

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am currently using the following sequence of commands in a Windows 7 PowerShell window.

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS SDK for .NET\bin\Net35\AWSSDK.dll"

$secretKeyID="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS"
$secretAccessKeyID="LONGKEYBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLABLAH"

$AWSclient=[Amazon.AWSClientFactory]::CreateAmazonS3Client($secretKeyID,$secretAccessKeyID)
```

However, I get this exception below.  Please let me know what Im doing wrong.  This is what I see most people using successfully.

```
Exception calling "CreateAmazonS3Client" with "2" argument(s): "No RegionEndpoint or ServiceURL configured"
At line:1 char:1
+ $oAWSclient=[Amazon.AWSClientFactory]::CreateAmazonS3Client($secretKeyID,$secret ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmazonClientException
```

One thing that I think is a problem is that my bucket is not checked for 'enable website hosting'.  Does this need to be set to true?  I just want to upload a file to the bucked via powershell script.

Answer (score 2):

Duh... I realized that I need to use the AWS Powershell because it has all the settings built into it.  Im not exactly sure how to properly refer to this version of powershell, but it is available after installing the AWS SDK.

Comment: It is called 'Windows PowerShell for AWS'.  You can view the difference by viewing the shortcut properties: in the target field, it specifies that the [AWS Powershell module](http://aws.amazon.com/powershell/) is loaded, and that the `Initialize-AWSDefaults` cmdlet is run. Running `Initialize-AWSDefaults` is what allowed you to use that particular overload of `CreateAmazonS3Client` without having to specify your own client configuration.

Comment: Yep... I noticed that too.  I thought it was a separate exe file but then the shortcut showed it was standard powershell with some options.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error specifically states that you're missing the RegionEndpoint or ServiceURL, you could also just include one of them.  Since you're connecting to S3, all you need is to include the RegionEndpoint.

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS SDK for .NET\bin\Net35\AWSSDK.dll"

$secretKeyID="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS"
$secretAccessKeyID="LONGKEYBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLABLAH"

$client = [Amazon.AWSClientFactory]::CreateAmazonS3Client($secretKeyID, $secretAccessKeyID, [Amazon.RegionEndpoint]::USEast1)
```

(Replace **USEast1** with the value configured with your S3 Bucket)